# Utility to populate clipboard from a selection of pre-saved texts

Tags: windows, clipboard

Having to use a somewhat stupid web application where I have to fill in the same or very similar texts over and over, I wondered whether there exists a utility that has the following features:

- Allow user-friendly selection of pre-saved texts to paste into an application (like web browser)
- Allow user-friendly management of pre-saved texts
- Optionally allow to "select and paste" most commonly used texts via hot-key
- Keep saved texts over reboots (i.e.: automatically load them when starting, and allow to save them to a file)
- Allow more than one set of "pre-saved texts"
- The utility should be Open Source preferably

Answer (score 1):

Ditto is clipboard manager which is open source, you can save copied items into folders to sort them out as well.
The product page says:

> [Ditto](https://ditto-cp.sourceforge.io) is an extension to the standard windows clipboard. It saves each item placed on the clipboard allowing you access to any of those items at a later time. Ditto allows you to save any type of information that can be put on the clipboard, text, images, html, custom formats, .....

Comment: So I tried Ditto; it's powerful, but it's not what I am looking for: (1) is populates the "store" automatically from any copy, but I want to manually populate the "registers". (2) selecting a specific register seems a bit complex to me (specifically finding unused hotkeys).